# Java Process Event listening

Tags: java

I have a situation where a jar file is running perfectly. Without having to change anything in the application:

1. Is there a way to figure out if that java application is generating any events i can listen and work with. Maybe some way to get ApplicationEvents from the process?

- Curious about this usecase
- it can always be achieved by stand alone event processor i know that already
- java version is 17, but it does not matter to the usecase

if there is a way of building this sort of architecture I am also interested in that, like generating custom event to be listened by any other process (user_login,... etc)

Comment: What kind of application is this?  What kind of event are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps JDK Flight Recorder could be of help. It's event based and it's possible to listen to events from another process, for example when a thread is started, a class is loaded or a lock is contended.

**Process A:**

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:class-loading=true 
       -XX:FlightRecorderOptions:repository=/data ...
```

**Process B:**

```
try (var es = EventStream.openRepository(Path.of("/data"))) {
 es.onEvent("jdk.ClassLoad", e -> {
   RecordedClass rc = e.getClass("loadedClass");
   System.out.println("Class loaded: " + rc.getName()));
 });
 es.start(); 
}
```

It's also possible to listen on events over the network using the RemoteRecordingStream class. Custom events can be created, but then you need to change the code or use an [instrumentation agent](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/11/16/jvm-performance-monitoring-jmc-agent#using_the_jmc_agent_plugin).